# iOS navigation views with both "back" and "save" buttons?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I am new to iOS programming and need some help on creating navigation. I have a top-level view, shown on the **left**. When the user presses the "Create New" button, the app should bring up the "One Journal Entry" view, shown on the **right**.

I currently have implemented the two views with navigation using a Navigation Controller. The problem I'm finding is that **there are now two ways to navigate back**: (1) Using the back button in the upper-left and (2) using the "Save" button, which saves to file. I think the back button should go back without saving, or perhaps that should be a "Cancel" button instead, in which case I should not use a Navigation Controller.

What is the standard UI approach for this type of problem?

[image] [image]

Comment: Yes you are following right approach. Create two UIBarButton with Canel and Save titles, Add target/selector/action method. Place Canel button on left and Save on right  side.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't change your views' architecture, it is pretty standard and handy with going back to previous view controller by upper-left button and going back also by save button, which IBAction can look like

```
-(IBAction)doSaveStuff:(UIButton *)sender
{
   // saving stuff
   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```